# Providing Predicate support in Java 6 library

Tags: java, java-8, backwards-compatibility

I am working with Java 8 mainly, but meanwhile also creating a library that uses Java 6, such that other people can use it as well in the future, as it is quite interesting.

The problem I have now is that I could very easily solve some issue by using Java 8's `Predicate<T>`, however I am unsure how to backport it.

I see the following options available, but they either have issues or I'm unsure how to use them:

- Use Google Guava's `Predicate<T>`, this however introduces a relatively big dependency where I do not really need it, also when a Java 8 user wants to use `Predicate`, then Google Guava's import for the `Predicate` class shows up.
- Use my own `Predicate<T>`, no big dependency, still the same issues as mentioned above.
- Use a custom name like `TessPredicate<T>`, as *Tess* will be relevant name in my project, does not feel that nice either.
- Use a name that makes sense in the project setting, such as (tentative) `RegexVerficationPredicate`, as it is a predicate in addition to using a regular expression, such that you can also do calculations on the elements. Bank codes, etc. usually have some checksum that you need to compute. Implemented as functional interface, this might be most feasible?
- Backport `java.util.function` from Java 8 to Java 6, is this even possible?

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t backport the `java.util.function` package due to the heavy use of `default` and `static` methods within these interfaces. Such a backport would look quite different.

I recommend creating your own `Predicate<T>` interface being as minimal as possible, i.e. having that single abstract method with the same signature as the Java 8 `Predicate<T>`. Having the same interface name and method signature like the well-known acts like a self-documentation.

This implies that programmers using Java 8 can still implement your predicate using a lambda expression or method reference (without even importing your `interface`). And using a Java 8 predicate is as easy as passing `predicate::test` to your method.

Adding a dependency to an entire 3rd party library just for one interface looks nasty to me.

Comment: Won't it interfere if someone wants to import `java.util.Predicate` in a Java 8 project using my library? When typing `Pred` for example, you can often (try to) auto-import the class.

Comment: As said, with Java 8 you don’t need to import the `interface`. But if you want to store predicates in a variable, you decide for *one* of the two interfaces and convert the predicates on-the-fly by passing `predicate::test` to methods expecting the other `interface`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend use of Guava. When I first used it, I was thinking the same way (too big dependency) then over time I started to use other features provided by guava and now I dont understand how do I do without them (those are my must have tools right now), code is clearer, faster and easily maintainable.

The fact that java SDK (especially java 8) is taking lot of features from Guava tells a lot... thus even tough you can write your own implementation, in a long term use of the library is more preferable...